# Is there a way to get cavities in your renders?

Tags: rendering

In the viewport menu for solid view, there is a cavity option.
I was wondering if there was a way for my models to render like that.

Comment: the solutions that come to mind are the Geometry > Pointiness node or the Ambient Occlusion node but they won't give the exact same effect, there's also a node group created by Wayward Art Company called Mask but it's stil not exactly what you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSOMqOmnwEY#t=2m45s   maybe someone has an another solution though

Comment: Hello :). You can render your current viewport through *View > Viewport Render Image* if that's what you mean.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Tyi03X9J8A4 Hi maybe this is helpful, This is the video I use I hope you get some help from this video

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do this...

Blender has a reader engine called "Workbench" which can be accessed in the render properties tab.

If you use the workbench render engine, you can get cavities, outlines, and much more!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)